# Delphi ADO connection to DBF files hangs when debugging

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado, dbf, dbase

I'm connecting to DBF files using Delphi 2009 ADO components and this connection string:

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=c:\mypath;
```

If c:\mypath doesn't exist, and I run the application inside the debugger, my app hangs. No exception is raised.

If I run the application without debugging, an exception is properly raised.

To reproduce I just create a new application, dropped an TADOConnection on the form, set the connection string and added this code to the OnCreate of the form:

```
ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please send a code snipped (and the property values). I tried the connection string and got a decent exception. Maybe you have some exceptions filtered?

Comment: You could try [Advantage Database Server](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/gettingstarted-delphi) components from Sybase to connect to .dbf files. They work better than ADO for this.

Comment: Indeed Delphi isn't raising the exception, running without the debugger I get an EOleException, but when I try to debug the application just frezes.